# Extract list of words from filenames

Tags: python, regex, list, filenames

I need to get a list of words, that files contains. Here is the files:

```
sub-Dzh_task-FmriPictures_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii
sub-Dzh_task-FmriVernike_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii
sub-Dzh_task-FmriWgWords_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii
sub-Dzh_task-RestingState_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii
```

I need to get that goes after task-<>_, so my list should looks:

```
['FmriPictures','FmriVernike','FmriWgWords','RestingState']
```

how can I implement it in python3?

Comment: Would splitting by hyphen and take third string if that's consistent file naming work?

Comment: could use regex `"task-(.*?)_"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python Solution for this which uses Regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> test_str = 'sub-Dzh_task-FmriPictures_space- 
MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask- 
Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii'
>>> re.search('task-(.*?)_', test_str).group(1)
'FmriPictures'
```

I think you can do the same for every string.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=["sub-Dzh_task-FmriPictures_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii",
"sub-Dzh_task-FmriVernike_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii",
"sub-Dzh_task-FmriWgWords_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii",
"sub-Dzh_task-RestingState_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii"]

k=[]
for i in l:

    k.append(i.split('-')[2].replace("_space",""))
print(k)
```

thats just approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your list and use `regex` to get the names from the strings like this example:

```
import re

a = ['sub-Dzh_task-FmriPictures_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii',
 'sub-Dzh_task-FmriVernike_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii',
 'sub-Dzh_task-FmriWgWords_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii',
 'sub-Dzh_task-RestingState_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii']

out = []
for elm in a:
    condition = re.search(r'_task-(.*?)_', elm)
    if bool(condition):
        out.append(condition.group(1))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
['FmriPictures', 'FmriVernike', 'FmriWgWords', 'RestingState']
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just simply replace

```
sub-Dzh_task-
```

and

```
_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_desc-preproc_bold_mask-Language_sub01_component_ica_s1_.nii
```

with null. Just empty those lines out and you'll get the file names.